VBA code | Open all files in folder, run format VBA code, then merge all onto one spreadsheet
I have several Excel files in a folder that I need to be formatted, and then the resultant files merged into one master spreadsheet.
1. I have the code to open all the files in the specified folder as follows:
Sub Open_Workbooks()

    Dim myPath As String
    Dim myFile As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    
    ' Specify the folder path containing the Excel files
        myPath = "C:\Users\Kuda\Documents\TRIAL BALANCES"
    
    
    ' Check for trailing backslash in folder path
        If Right(myPath, 1) <> "\" Then myPath = myPath & "\"
    
    
    ' Find the first Excel file in the folder
    myFile = Dir(myPath & "*.xls*")
    
    
    ' Loop through all Excel files in the folder
    Do While myFile <> ""
        ' Open the workbook
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(myPath & myFile)
        
        ' Move to the next file (this line is essential to avoid an endless loop)
        myFile = Dir
    Loop
End Sub

2. The formatting code will be:
Call tb_cleanup()

3. Now I need a 3rd code that applies code #2 to all the open spreadsheets, and then copies the formatted data from each open spreadsheet, and then pastes it, stacking them one after the other onto one master spreadsheet.
#4 The Fourth code would be one singular code which has the above 3 all in one.
So, could I get help with a code for point 3 & 4 as per the above.
The code for tb-cleanup is
Sub tb_cleanup()

Dim A, B


If Range("D11").Value <> "Account" Then

    MsgBox "Not applicable here.", vbOKOnly, "FOR TB ONLY!!"
    Exit Sub
    
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    
    A = Range("A2").Value
    B = Range("B2").Value
    
    
    Cells.Select
    Selection.UnMerge
    Columns("C:C").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    
    
    Rows("1:10").Select
    Range("A10").Activate
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    
    Range("G1").Value = "Business Unit"
    Range("H1").Value = "Month"
    Range("I1").Value = "Year"
    
Dim xRow
xRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas2, LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False _
        , SearchFormat:=False).Row
         
         
Dim k

k = xRow - 5

    ' delete last unnec rows
    Rows(k & ":" & xRow).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    
    

xRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas2, LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False _
        , SearchFormat:=False).Row
         
         
    'put BU + Date

    Range("G2:G" & xRow).FormulaR1C1 = A
    
    Range("H2:H" & xRow).FormulaR1C1 = Format(B, "MMM")
    Range("I2:I" & xRow).FormulaR1C1 = Format(B, "yyyy")
    
    
    Range("G2").Select
    
    Range("B2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
    
    Range("A1:I" & xRow).Select
    Selection.Columns.AutoFit
   
    Range("G2").Select
    
    Call myTable
    
xRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas2, LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False _
        , SearchFormat:=False).Row
         

    Range("B2:B" & xRow).Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
        Selection.InsertIndent 1
        
        
        ActiveWindow.Zoom = 75
    Range("A1:I" & xRow).Select
    Selection.RowHeight = 18
    
    With Selection
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = -1
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Aptos Display"
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMajor
    End With
    
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Aptos Display"
        .Size = 11
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMajor
    End With
    
    Range("D2:F" & xRow).Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "_(* #,##0_);_(* (#,##0);_(* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
    
    Range("A1:I" & xRow).Select
    Selection.Columns.AutoFit
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlHairline
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlHairline
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlHairline
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlHairline
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlHairline
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlHairline
    End With
       
    
    
    Range("A1").Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

 
End Sub

call myTable is as follows:
Sub myTable()

    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    With Selection.Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent4
        .TintAndShade = 0.599993896298105
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

    Range("A1").Select
    
    
    
End Sub


Give it a go then and let us know where you get stuck.

So what is your question?

@MarkS. - the question is on point 3 & 4. I need codes for those

Please share the code of tb_cleanup so it can be appropriately modified (at least a worksheet object as a parameter added): Sub tb_cleanup(ByVal ws As Worksheet). Also, what about the Master sheet?

@MarkS. - I have updated the code in the Question. It's pretty long. If there is way to make it shorter, have a go at it too, please.  Regarding the Master Sheet, that's the final destination for all the data to be pasted on, from one sheet to the next, being pasted and stacked one after another on the Master Sheet.

Instead of opening all files at once and making the modifications, this will open them individually 1 by 1 and loop through the entire folder until complete.
1. Create a master file in your folder location and name it "1. File Consolidator". Make sure all the files in the folder being opened by the Master File are in .xlsb format (or if different, change the extension type in the "AllFiles" macro below).
2. Open the master file and re-name the tab to "File Consolidator".
3. Create a macro in which you will run:
Sub AllFiles()
  Dim folderPath As String
  Dim filename As String
  Dim wb As Workbook
  Dim wb2 As Workbook
  folderPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path

    If Right(folderPath, 1) <> "\" Then folderPath = folderPath + "\"
    filename = Dir(folderPath & "*.xlsb")
    Do While filename <> ""
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & filename)

   'Call a subroutine here to operate on the just-opened workbook
    Call tb_cleanup

   'Call 2nd subroutine to copy and paste opened workbook into master file
    Call GenFileToCall

    filename = Dir
    Loop
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  MsgBox ("File Consolidator ran successfully")
End Sub

Create your 2nd macro "GenFileToCall" (called in the above), to copy the open workbooks to your master file:
Sub GenFileToCall()
  Dim Lastrow As Long
  Set wb = Application.Workbooks("1. File Consolidator.xlsm")
  Set wb2 = Application.ActiveWorkbook

    If ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then wb2.Sheets("Sheet1").ShowAllData

   'Find last row in wb2
    With wb2.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Lastrow = .Range("A:AS").Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
    End With

   'Copy range from A2:AS until last row then close
    wb2.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:AS" & Lastrow).Copy
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

   'Make wb1 active workbook again
    wb.Activate

   'Find last row in wb1
    With wb.Sheets("File Consolidator")
    Lastrow = .Range("A:AS").Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
    End With

   'Paste in wb1 after last row
    wb.Sheets("File Consolidator").Range("A" & Lastrow + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    wb.Sheets("File Consolidator").Range("A" & Lastrow + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

   'Close wb2 (Test File)
    wb2.Close
End Sub

